# TypeScript normalizing intersection explanation

Tags: typescript

I've been writing TypeScript helpers to normalize type intersections (see https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/lknqyz/tool_to_normalize_types_specifically_intersections/). I've stumbled upon a method that seems to work pretty well generically, at least in terms of flattening one level of the intersection (which is what I want):

```
type A = { foo: string; bar: number };
type B = { baz: { foo: number } };

type Normalize<T> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] } & {};

type C1 = A & B // A & B 
type C2 = Normalize<A & B> // { foo: string; bar: number; baz: { foo: number} };
```

Without the `& {}` part, the helper works for simple types (like A and B above) but gives up with more complex ones, i.e. something like:

```
type WeakNormalize<T> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] };
type C3 = WeakNormalize<A & B> // May return "WeakNormalize<A & B>" if A and B are complex
```

Anyone got an explanation why/how the `& {}` works? Also, is this just a feature of the LSP, or is this actually meaningful on the type level?